# Parsing .Pls Playlists in Xcode

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to programm a simple audioplayer in Xcode using an instance of AVPlayer.
To access the needed URL in a .Pls file my current functions looks like this:

```
- (NSURL*)dirtyFirstTrack:(NSURL*)path
{
    NSString *data = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:path encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding    error:nil];
    NSString *urlString = [[[[data componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]objectAtIndex:2] componentsSeparatedByString:@"="] objectAtIndex:1];
    return [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
}
```

this does not seem a good solution to me, but maybe one of you knows a better way to do it.